# Display error when Windows Service has exception in OnPause

Tags: c#, windows-services

In a windows service, I have the need for preventing an OnPause from succeeding.  i.e. a job is currently being processed.

I throw an exception and do not call base.OnPause(), but the dialog from the Services application is:

> Windows could not pause the BTR Evolution Service service on Local Computer. The service did not return an
>   error.  This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service
>   error. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

How do I 'return an error' or change this message to something a bit more useful?

I know other questions have asked on how to prevent the 'Stop' from happening, but from my understanding you shouldn't ever prevent stop from happening (b/c could be a system initiated event) but I can prevent pause from happening (b/c this would be a user initiated event??).

So I am only trying to prevent (not request more time or anything) a Pause from happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling delays during stop/pause requests on Windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146680/handling-delays-during-stop-pause-requests-on-windows-service)

Comment: Ok, I missed that you want to prevent the OnPause completely, not just delay it while waiting for some job to finish. I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: Will you sometimes honor the OnPause? Because if you want to prevent it entirely, there is a property where you specify if your service supports pause/continue.

Comment: Yes, I'll honor if no 'jobs' are running.

Comment: Do you have to display something if you can't pause? My understanding is that your service can do whatever it wants when paused. It could return normally from the OnPause, but actually continue and finish any outstanding jobs. From the documentation: *"OnPause does nothing to the service that you do not define it to do."*

Comment: I guess I'm just envision an 'admin' wanting to pause service to stop job processing and maybe manually update database or other configuration files or assemblies...but if a job is running they shouldn't do it 'yet'.  So want to throw exception to 'user' who tried to do 'pause' so they know not to continue.

Comment: There is no option to display a custom message.  When you say you support pausing then an admin will expect you to pause in, oh, no more than 5 seconds when he asks you to pause.  Take any longer and you'll just annoy him.  Take longer than 30 seconds and the service manager will give up waiting for you.  You can call RequestAdditionalTime() if you don't mind annoying the admin.  But keep in mind that he won't hesitate to kill your service, like annoyed admins are wont to do, so you'd better use a transaction to update the dbase.

Comment: @HansPassant Doesn't the quote 'The service did not return an error.' imply that it is possible to somehow return an error code?

Comment: Do you really need to pause? You only need pause as an option if start-up is very expensive/slow operation. If startup is quick, then stop/start does the job instead of pause/unpause.

Comment: In our situation, a Pause would kind of be like a 'request' of whether it is safe or not to stop processing and do some maintenance while Stop would be kind of a 'taskkill' type operation.  So yes, I was hoping for Pause.  Didn't realize it would be so complicated to send an error number back or special exception or something.  I guess I'll just live with generic error message and check event log for more details if needed.